# QPixmap: Must construct a QGuiApplication before a QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am writing a simple C++ and QT QML program, where QML will get value from C++.

C++

```
main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QQuickView view;
  QQmlContext* context = view.engine()->rootContext();
  context->setContextProperty("_aString",QString("KADB"));
  context->setContextProperty("_aSize",QSize(800,600));
  context->setContextProperty("_bakcground",QColor(Qt::lightGray));
}
```

QML
main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle{
    width: _aSize.width
    height: _aSize.height
    color: _bakcground

    Column {
        Text { text: "The string: " + _aString}
        Text { text: "The size: " + _aSize}
    }
}
```

When I compile, look ok.
But when I run, it got below error:

QPixmap: Must construct a QGuiApplication before a QPixmap

I am using :
Qt Creator 4.10.2
Based on Qt 5.13.2 (MSVC 2017, 32 bit)

Built on Nov 4 2019 02:17:31

From revision 7c61e936ce

I am using a QT Widgets Application.
Can someone help, thanks so much.

Comment: Yes, you must create a QGuiApplication before doing anything else.

Comment: You say you are using Qt Widgets Application... but there is nothing like `QApplication` in your code. You need to instantiate the application object, either `QApplication` (if you are using widgets) or `QGuiApplication` (which is what you probably want since you are using QML). And you must do it before using `QPixmap`. So the error message syas exactly what you need to do.

Comment: When one is using " app = QApplication([]) ", what would one need to do to add an icon to the window?